# database/sql cannot select query when args number is huge

Tags: postgresql, go, ojdbc

#### What version of Go are you using (`go version`)?

```
$ go version
go version go1.14 linux/amd64
```

#### Does this issue reproduce with the latest release?

yes

#### What operating system and processor architecture are you using (`go env`)?

```
$ go env
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/zabludovsky/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/home/zabludovsky/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/zabludovsky/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY="gl.rosst.ru/backend/*"
GONOSUMDB="gl.rosst.ru/backend/*"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/zabludovsky/go"
GOPRIVATE="gl.rosst.ru/backend/*"
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/zabludovsky/go/src/awesomeProject1/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build174435943=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

#### What did you do?

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main()  {
    err := selectFromDb(65536)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    println("where was no errors!")
}

func selectFromDb(argsNumber int) (err error){
    //open connect to postgres database, put your database connection string below, instead of second argument
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://mayber:password@localhost:5432/test?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    //preparing query, you can call this func with argsNumber = 10(or some not huge number)
    //to check that it is working correct
    var args []interface{}
    query := "SELECT id FROM test_tbl WHERE id IN ("
    for i := 0; i < argsNumber; i++ {
        args = append(args, strconv.Itoa(i))
        query = fmt.Sprintf("%s $%d, ", query, i+1)
        fmt.Printf("preparing query, %d/%d \n", i, argsNumber)
    }
    query = fmt.Sprintf("%s);", query[:len(query)-2])
    fmt.Println("preparing finished:")

    //uncomment string bellow to see result query and check it
    //fmt.Println(query)


    //preparing query
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(query)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    //selecting
    rows, err := stmt.Query(args...)
    if err != nil{
        return
    }

    //closing db connection
    err = rows.Close()
    if err != nil{
        return
    }

    return
}
```

#### What did you expect to see?

```
preparing query, 0/65536
preparing query, 1/65536
...
preparing query, 60535/65536
preparing finished:
where was no errors!
```

#### What did you see instead?

```
preparing finished:
panic: sql: expected 0 arguments, got 65536
```

for more details https://github.com/GlebZabl/golang_postgres_bug

Comment: IN statements have a database dependent limitation either in number of items or length of the string. If you have a large number, create a temporary table with your args and use a join to get to the result.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen, nope, that is not postgres limit. i've try query with even 65540 in usual jetbrains db console and it works fine. If you want to make sure, just copy my code, replace 33th string with ```query = fmt.Sprintf("%s %d, ", query, i+1)```, uncomment printing final query to console(40th string), copy that to your db console and execute. So it is exactly database/sql lib bug, connected with parsing query string

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen, sorry, you are right about sql limit on parameters number, it it exactly not more then 65535(https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/7559d8ebfa11d98728e816f6b655582ce41150f3/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-exec.c#L1304), but error message is totally incorrect and have to be fixed.

Comment: Just because you can do something does not mean it is a good idea to do it. Ninetynine times out of 100, if you have a large number of  `IN` values, the data model is over- or undernormalized. Furthermore, you prepare the query with all the args already in place. You should try with a parametrized query. Show us the real datamodel, and the according code, and we might be able to actually help you. In its current form, this is a more of a bug report than an actual question.

Comment: ok, it is really more bug report then question, sorry. I`ve already started few issues on database/sql and github.com/lib/pq